# Connect Appserver of progress open edge through node.js

Tags: node.js, progress-4gl, openedge

Does anyone have experience, information or some (coding) examples about a solution to establish a connection between the appserver of progress and node.js!? The aim is to create REST-Services to the db which can be accessed by the web like an angular-app.

Thanks for any advice

Christian

Comment: What version of OE are you thinking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 11.2 (and enhanced in later versions) you can create REST-based applications utilizing the AppServer as a platform. ProDatasets are used as output (they convert easily to xml and/or json).

This is all explained in the Web Services part of the documentation. I'm providing a link below.

**Basic steps**

*You need to consult the manual for all these steps...*

1. Create an ABL program with input parameters (could be a parameter, a temp-table or a dataset) and and a single output parameter (could be a temp-table, a dataset or a single character or longchar parameter).
2. Add ABL-specific REST annotation to the program
3. Map the parameters in OpenEdge Studio
4. Setup REST agents with the `restman` utility
5. Export a "WAR-file" and deploy your webservice.

Calling the web service from node.js should be no greater problem than calling any REST based web service.

In versions prior to 11.2 you can "fake it and make it" utilizing WebSpeed. You can create a webspeed program that read parameters from the query-string (using `get-field()`) and then writes a response to the "webstream". Use either the `WRITE-XML` or `WRITE-JSON` methods on a temp-table or a dataset for writing the result. Don't forget to add a good MIME type though... This might not be as robust and customizable but it will work...

[OE 11.4 Product Documentation - Web Services](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/dvwsv/dvwsv.pdf) *See chapter "II Creating OpenEdge REST Web Services"*

These might also be useful:

[OE 11.4 Product Documentation - Working with XML](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/dvxml/dvxml.pdf)

[OE 11.4 Product Documentation - Working with JSON](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/dvjsn/dvjsn.pdf)